# Issue certificate with cloudflare and esdb - DeadlineExceeded

Tags: .net-core, grpc, cloudflare, event-sourcing, eventstoredb

I'm new developer for eventstore
I try setting certificate to eventstore.
With admin UI it work, but when i request from my code it not working

i'm using nginx to pass_proxy to eventstore

I have eventstore.conf

[image]

nginx config

[image]

and appendstream code as:

[image]

i config eventstore with code

```
services.AddEventStoreClient("esdb://admin:changeit@esdb.megiservices.com:2113?tls=true");
```

or

```
services.AddEventStoreClient("esdb://admin:changeit@esdb.megiservices.com?tls=true");
```

or

```
services.AddEventStoreClient("esdb://admin:changeit@96.9.211.102?tls=true");
```

in cloudflare i add an dns record

[image]

it's working when i request to https://esdb.megiservices.com/

but i retrieve error when call eventstore via code. Message:

Status(StatusCode="DeadlineExceeded", Detail="")

What can i do to fix this issue?

I using:

EventStore.Client.Grpc.Streams : 20.10.0
Grpc.Net.Client: 2.38.0

Thanks for your support

Answer (score 0):

I don't think EventStoreDB gRPC API was tested using a reverse proxy.

As a bare minimum, you need to [enable the http2 proxy](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-nginx-with-http-2-support-on-ubuntu-18-04) on Nginx, and it might solve the problem, although not guaranteed.

Comment: Thanks for your support, i tried enable http2 but not working.

Comment: I honestly don't know. gRPC is a streaming protocol, not many proxy servers properly support it.